# How to change/set screenshot dir. for appium library in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

i am facing problem with setting the screenshot directory for Appium library in robot framework. Currently it is able to take screenshot at the root where output xml/reports are getting generated. But i want screenshot to be saved in other directory let say /result folder.

Any help appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use "Screenshot library" and use keyword "Set Screenshot Directory" to set directory  where you want to save.

```
Set Screenshot Directory   /your_path
```

Comment: Hello Sachhya. This dint work as it took screenshot at the main dir. i am looking out for something which can be set globally in appium like we have for selenium . dont know if this can work like it.

Answer (score 0):

richard try this

```
***Setting***
Library     Screenshot

*** Test Cases ***

My Test Case

Screenshot.Set Screenshot Directory /home/richard
Take Screenshot     my_image.jpg
```

but you must make sure that you add "Screenshot library" in your setting portion.you need to specify that you are accessing this keyword from Screenshot Library, because some time two libraries has same keyword so they shows ambiguity during execution